# I'm having trouble understanding this code which produces permutations using recursion

Tags: python, recursion, generator, permutation

```
def permute2(seq):
    if not seq:                           # Shuffle any sequence: generator
        yield seq                         # Empty sequence
    else:
        for i in range(len(seq)):
            rest = seq[:i] + seq[i+1:]        # Delete current node
            for x in permute2(rest):          # Permute the others
                # In some cases x = empty string
                yield seq[i:i+1] + x          # Add node at front

for x in permute2('abc'):
    print('result =',x)
```

When yielding the first result (`'abc'`) the value of `i == 0` and `seq == 'abc'`. The control flow then takes it to the top of the outer for loop where `i == 1`, which makes sense; however, `seq == 'bc'`, which completely baffles me.

Comment: I would recommend stepping through the code in a debugger. That should make it very clear how exactly the flow of execution is happening, and what all the variables are at any given step.

Comment: Put a `print(seq)` at the beginning of the function and see if what it displays makes things clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to explain it from an inductive standpoint.

Let the length of the sequence be n.
Our base case is n = 0, when we simply return the empty sequence (it is the only permutation).

If n > 0, then:
To define a permutation, we must first begin by choosing the first element.  To define all permutations, obviously we must consider all elements of the sequence as possible first elements.

Once we have chosen the first element, we now need to choose the rest of the elements.  But this is just the same as finding all the permutations of sequence without the element we chose.  This new sequence is of length n-1, and so by induction we can solve it.

Slightly altering the original code to mimic my explanation and hopefully make it clearer:

```py
def permute2(seq):
    length = len(seq)
    if (length == 0):
        # This is our base case, the empty sequence, with only one possible permutation.
        yield seq
        return

    for i in range(length):
        # We take the ith element as the first element of our permutation.
        first_element_as_single_element_collection = seq[i:i+1]
        # Note other_elements has len(other_elements) == len(seq) - 1
        other_elements = seq[:i] + seq[i+1:]
        for permutation_of_smaller_collection in permute2(other_elements):
            yield first_element_as_single_element_collection + permutation_of_smaller_collection

for x in permute2('abc'):
    print('result =',x)
```

Hopefully it is clear that the original code does exactly the same thing as the above code.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I see that they do the same thing. I went ahead and coded it so I could run it with added print statements and I still can't say that I understand what I'm seeing on a step by step basis.

Comment: Hmm.  Perhaps try fully enumerating the result of `permute2(other_elements)` into a variable before iterating it - that would allow you to inspect the result.  If it's not clear what I mean, just say and I'll edit it into the answer.